# Htaccess rewrite rule conflicting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It seems like I can't have to rewrite rules of the same page with the same amount of parameters.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule forums/(.*)/(.*).php/(.*)$ forums.php?forums_view_id=$1&forums_view_seo=$2&page=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule forums/(.*)/(.*).php/create$ forums.php?forums_view_id=$1&forums_view_seo=$2&create=true
```

Only the first one works. But if I remove the first one, then the 2nd one works. How can I fix this?

Comment: Change their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule forums/(.*)/(.*).php/create$ forums.php?forums_view_id=$1&forums_view_seo=$2&create=true [L]
RewriteRule forums/(.*)/(.*).php/(.*)$ forums.php?forums_view_id=$1&forums_view_seo=$2&page=$3 [L]
```